# Using Tesseract OCR in C#

Tags: c#, ocr, clipboard, tesseract

I have trying to deploy tesseract for reading the clipboard image through the code below in a C# window.form. But, a black commandline window appears and nothing happens.

```
 private void b1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ofd1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            var img = new Bitmap(ofd1.FileName);
            var ocr = new TessBaseAPI("./tessdata", "eng", OcrEngineMode.DEFAULT);
            var page = ocr.SetImage(img);
            tb1.Text = page.ToString();


        }

    }
```

The error it gives is `cannot convert from 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' to 'Leptonica.Pix'` hope this can be improved.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of creating a bitmap, try using a Pix object like:

```
var img = Tesseract.Pix.LoadFromFile(ofd1.FileName)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have made a big work around. I am using the pytesseract and tell it the location where tesseract-OCR is placed. And, finally the pytesseract function of image_to_string is invoked that does the task. I gave up the idea of directly using this.